# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' error

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am facing this issue when trying to login a user into the app.

The login details are being sent to the server and after
necessary authentication the result is sent back to the user(only username and the token generated is sent back to the user - need this data only),
but while running forEach to insert the data it then throws an error **type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'** , not able to pinpoint the exact line creating this issue

If someone can please help me to resolve this issue.

Login.dart

```
class Login with ChangeNotifier{
  User user;
  String token;

  Login({this.user,this.token});

  Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    user = json['user'] != null ? new User.fromJson(json['user']) : null;
    token = json['token'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.user != null) {
      data['user'] = this.user.toJson();
      data['token'] = this.token;
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class User with ChangeNotifier{
  String createdAt;
  String sId;
  String userName;
  String password;
  int iV;
  

  User(
      {this.createdAt,
      this.sId,
      this.userName,
      this.password,
      this.iV,
      
      });

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    sId = json['_id'];
    userName = json['username'];
    password = json['password'];
    iV = json['__v'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['createdAt'] = this.createdAt;
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['username'] = this.userName;
    data['password'] = this.password;
    data['__v'] = this.iV;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Provider.dart

```
class LoginProvider with ChangeNotifier {

 List<Login> _loginDetails = [];

List<Login> get items {
  return [..._loginDetails];
}

Future<void> addLoginDetails(User loginDetailscheck ) async {
print("reached");
Map<String, String> headers = {
"Content-Type": "charset=utf-8",    
"Content-type": "application/json"};

  const url = 'http://localhost:3000/login/cred';

 try
  {
  var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers,body:  
   json.encode({
    "user_name": loginDetailscheck.userName,
    "password": loginDetailscheck.password,
    "created_at": loginDetailscheck.createdAt,
    "_id":loginDetailscheck.sId
  })
  );
  final map  = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;
  final List<Login> loadData = [];
  map.forEach((prodId, datacheck) {
    loadData.add( LoginPage(
      user: User(
        userName: datacheck['username'],
        ),
      token: json.decode(response.body)['token'],
    )
    );
    print(datacheck['username']);
    print(json.decode(response.body)['token']);
   });

  if(response.statusCode == 201) {
    _loginDetails = loadData;
  print(json.decode(response.body));
  notifyListeners();    
  }else{
    print('invalid data ');
  }
  }catch(error) {
    throw (error);
  }

}
}
```

Data format received:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "Tom",
        "__v": 82
    },
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzICJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZjA1NmY5YWI3NNDc1MDF9.zxii8_5DX9dSg-htXXbPfz0qKDI1"
}
```

ui.dart

```
class LoginHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginHomeState createState() => _LoginHomeState();
}

class _LoginHomeState extends State<LoginHome> {


final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

var _dLogin = User(
    createdAt: DateTime.now().toString(),
    userName: '',
    password: '',


Future<void> _savedetails() async{
  final isValid = _form.currentState.validate();
  if(!isValid) {
     return;
  }

);
  _form.currentState.save();
  await Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).addLoginDetails(_dLogin) 
        .catchError((error) {
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Network error...'),));
  }
  );


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  
         Column(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            Container(
             child: SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Form(
               key:_form,
               child: Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 70,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 40,left: 10,right: 10),
                     child: TextFormField(
                     textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),    
                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                         errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0,color:Colors.transparent),
                         contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0,left: 100),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      prefixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:20),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.email,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ), 
                      ),   
                       hintText: 'Username',
                       //labelText: 'E-mail',
                       hintStyle: TextStyle(color:Colors.grey[400],
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                       ),
                       ),
                       onSaved: (value) => {
                         _dLogin = User(
                           userName: value,
                           password: _editLogin.password,
                           createdAt: _editLogin.createdAt,
                           sId: _editLogin.sId,
                         )
                       },
                      validator: (value) {
                      if (value.length == 0)
                      return "";                     
                      else
                      return null; 
                   },
                    ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: myboxDecoration(),
                  height: 70,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 20,bottom: 10,left: 10,right: 10),
                     child: TextFormField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white
                        ),   
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0,color:Colors.transparent),  
                      contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      prefixIcon: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:20),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.lock_outline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ), // icon is 48px widget.
                      ),
                      
                       hintText: 'Password',
                       hintStyle: TextStyle(color:Colors.grey[400],
                       fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                       
                       ),
                       
                       ),
                       onSaved: (value) => {
                         _dLogin = User(
                           userName: _editLogin.userName,
                           password: value,
                           createdAt: _editLogin.createdAt,
                           sId: _editLogin.sId,
                         )
                       },
                       validator: (value) {
                       if (value.length == 0)
                       return "";                     
                       else if (value.length <= 5)
                       return "";                     
                     else
                       return null; 
                   },
                   obscureText: true,
                    ),
                ),
                
                Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 200
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,right:20,top:50), 
                        child: FlatButton(
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child:    
                            Text('LOGIN',
                            style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0, 
                            ),
                            ),
                          onPressed:  _saveNotification, 
                            ),
                      ),      
                 ],
                 
             )
    )
             ),
           ),
           ]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just check this two parameters iV and Sid  if they are int and you calling the String parameter parameter which is integer, just change it to toString().

Comment: Hi Sagar i have checked this and the datatype are matching...I also removed the iV and Sid as they are not important but still getting the same error

Comment: Just try to restart maybe the changes might not be affected,can you add some ui code and sample json data so that I can check it on my side.

Comment: json data can be found above in the data format received section of the question..let me know if this is what u were looking for....additionally i have just edited the question to provide the UI code as well

Comment: There seems to be an issue in the forEach loop but not able to figure out so if you can please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code I see that you need to itearate for each loop on map['user'] and not on just map which will give you the inner object data. I am just writing it just check by printing the values in the foreach loop. I did not check it on my laptop but will soon check it.

Just check the edit i have taken a sample example your foreach loop is having a problem.

```
 String response = '''{
    "user": {
        "username": "Tom",
        "__v": 82
    },
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzICJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZjA1NmY5YWI3NNDc1MDF9.zxii8_5DX9dSg-htXXbPfz0qKDI1"
}''';

  

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    Map item = json.decode(response);
    print(item['token']);
    item['user'].forEach((key, value) {
      print(key);
      print(value);
      
    });

  }
```

Comment: Hi Sagar...can you please provide the code of the above as i checked from my end and seems the prodId is capturing the user data but the error is still thrown

Comment: Check the edits i have made, the problem was with the foreach loop where you need to iterate through the users

Comment: Hi sagar made the changes and it works now ...thank you for your help :)